# A vetical slideshow animation

Tags: html, css, sass

Im trying to make a vertical slideshow animation, the way i want it to work is whenever i click on the radio buttons, the pictures move corresponding to the button i clicked (for example when i click the second radio button i want the second picture to smoothly slide up from the buttom and get displayed, and what i tried is making a div that containes the images, and give each image a height of : 100vh and the div container contains 4 images,so i got an overflow, but i've hidden it, so to create an illusion of the animation, i want the container div to move up or down correspondingly with radio button thats selected by using the transform: translateY() property, when i seperatly give a constant value to translateY()(for example:

```
.home-main{
   transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

) it works just fine and i get the next picture displayed, but i dont want to hard code it for each image, so i used a for loop (im using sass) and i couldnt figure out why it didnt work, this is the code for it :

this is the block of scss where i tried to make the animation using the for loop:

```
@for $i from 1 to 4 {
    input:checked .home-main{
        transform: translateY($i * -25%);
    }
}
```

scss:

```
html{
    font-size: 10px;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: $primary-font;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $primary-color;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.burger-btns-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 1rem;
    width: 4rem;
    margin: 0  1rem 4.5rem 0;
    z-index: 1;
    .burger-btn{
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: $secondary-color;
        height: 25%;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 20%;
        pointer-events: none;
        @include transition-slider-label-and-burger-button;
    }

    .line1{
        transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(2.2rem);
        background-color: $primary-color;
    }

    .line2{
        transform: translateX(-1rem);
        opacity: 0;
        background-color: $primary-color;

    }

    .line3{
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-2.2rem);
        background-color: $primary-color;
    }

}

.logo{
    margin: 1.2rem;
    @include transition-logo;
    img{
        height: 4rem;
        width: 4rem;
    }
}
.logo-not-displayed{
    opacity: 0;
}

.main-nav{
    margin-top: 10rem;
    padding: 20rem 0;
    height:
     100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10rem;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;
    @include transition-slide;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: $secondary-color;
    ul{
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        list-style: none;
        li{
            padding-left: 20rem;
            transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        }
    }
}
.main-nav-active{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    @for $i from 1 to 6 {
        li:nth-child(#{$i}){
            padding-left: 0;
            transition-delay: ($i * 0.1s);
        }
    }
}

.sliders{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    right: 3rem;

    label{
        border: .2rem solid $secondary-color;
        border-radius: 360%;
        margin: 1rem 0;
        height: 1.5rem;
        width: 1.5rem;
        @include transition-slider-label-and-burger-button;
    }

    input{
        display: none;
        &:checked+label{
            background-color: $secondary-color;
        }
    }
}

.home-main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
}

@for $i from 1 to 4 {
    input:checked .home-main{
        transform: translateY($i * -25%);
    }
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="chef-hat.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="burger-btns-container">
            <span class="burger-btn"></span>
            <span class="burger-btn"></span>
            <span class="burger-btn"></span>
        </div>
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu menu-selected"><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
                <li class="menu menu-selected"><a href="menu.html">menu</a></li>
                <li class="about about-selected"><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
                <li class="chefs chefs-selected"><a href="chefs.html">our chefs</a></li>
                <li class="sign sign-selected"><a href="sign.html">sign in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="sliders">
        <input type="radio" class="page-sliders" id="slide1" name="hh">
        <label for="slide1"></label>
        <input type="radio" class="page-sliders" id="slide2" name="hh">
        <label for="slide2"></label>
        <input type="radio" class="page-sliders" id="slide3" name="hh">
        <label for="slide3"></label>
        <input type="radio" class="page-sliders" id="slide4" name="hh">
        <label for="slide4"></label>
    </div>
    <main class="home-main main">
        <img src="css/main-background1.jpg">
        <img src="css/main-background2.jpg">
        <img src="css/main-background3.jpg">
        <img src="css/main-background4.jpg">
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `.home-main` element is not a descendant of your `input` elements.

Comment: @Quciksilver so i should put .home-main and the input elements within the same container of what?

Comment: Yes, you can put them to the same level and use the `+` selector in CSS to select them. If you don't want to change the layout, you may also use JavaScript.